# how to add dynamic enable/disable checkboxes to dynamic table in jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox

I'm building a form with dynamic rows (I've solved it already) and dynamic enable-disable checkboxes which I can't resolve

this code should work like this:
I'm choosing "which-cruise" and then I can add one/six classes but I should first click "your-extra-options" to have 6-checkboxes enabled. On the first row it works great but when I add (by cloning) more rows every "your-extra-options" checkbox handles only with enabling/disabling 6-checkboxes from the first row

**HTML**

```
<table class="reference" id="secondaryEmails" style="width: 800px;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="which-cruise">
                <option>First Cruise</option>
                <option>Second Cruise</option>
                <option>Third Cruise</option>
                <option>Fourth Cruise</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="your-extra-options" value="Your Extra Options" onclick="enableDisable(this,'extra_class','first_class','second_class','third_class','lower_class','rock-bottom_class')" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" name="extra_class" value="Extra Class" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" name="first_class" value="First Class" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" name="second_class" value="Second Class" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" name="third_class" value="Third Class" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" name="lower_class" value="Lower Class" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" name="rock-bottom_class" value="Rock-Bottom Class" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="breakfast" value="Breakfast" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="lunch" value="Lunch" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" name="add" value="ADD" class="tr_clone_add2">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**script**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("input.tr_clone_add").live('click', function () {
        var $tr = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
        var $clone = $tr.clone();
        $clone.find(':text').val('');
        $tr.after($clone);
    });

    var count = $("table.reference tr").length;

    $("input.tr_clone_add2").live('click', function () {
        count++;
        var $clone = $("#secondaryEmails tbody tr:first").clone();
        $clone.attr({
            id: "emlRow_" + count,
            name: "emlRow_" + count,
            style: "" // remove "display:none"
        });
        $clone.find("input,select").each(function () {
            $(this).attr({
                id: $(this).attr("id") + count,
                name: $(this).attr("name") + count
            });
        });
        $("#secondaryEmails tbody").append($clone);
    });

    function enableDisable(oChk) {
        var disable = !oChk.checked;
        var arglen = arguments.length;
        var obj, startIndex = 1;
        var frm = oChk.form;
        for (var i = startIndex; i < arglen; i++) {
            obj = frm.elements[arguments[i]];
            if (typeof obj == "object") {
                if (document.layers) {
                    if (disable) {
                        obj.onfocus = new Function("this.blur()");
                        if (obj.type == "text") obj.onchange = new Function("this.value=this.defaultValue");
                    } else {
                        obj.onfocus = new Function("return");
                        if (obj.type == "text") obj.onchange = new Function("return");
                    }
                } else obj.disabled = disable;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please format your code and try again. Also, for such extensive code it is better if you put a fiddle together :)

Comment: Alexander sure do, but what do you mean with format my code?

Comment: I mean http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: done & done, any better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution relies on jQuery >= v1.7 but you should be able to do something similar with the deprecated live() method instead of the newer on() method.

Basically we add an event listener to the table itself so it doesn't matter how many rows are added to the table dynamically.  Every time a click on a checkbox with the class "your-extra-options" is detected, we hunt down the relevant class checkboxes in that particular row and enable/disable them as appropriate.  Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#secondaryEmails');
    table.on('click', '.your-extra-options', function() {
        var checkbox = $(this);
        // Find all relevant checkboxes in the same row as the clicked "your-extra-options" checkbox
        var class_checkboxes = checkbox.closest('tr').find('.class-checkbox');
        var disable_classes = checkbox.prop('checked') ? false : true;
        class_checkboxes.prop('disabled', disable_classes);
    });
});
```

In terms of your HTML, this requires you to add the class "your-extra-options" to your first row input with the name "your-extra-options" and also add the class "class-checkbox" to each checkbox that relates to a booking class (e.g. first class, lower class etc.)

You should also remove the onclick="" from the "your-extra-options" checkbox since it will no longer be used.

Example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kw3Ru/)

Comment: behic thanks for solution - I'm trying to implement it and as for now nothing happens - except this script which you provided do I need to change something in html code? or else?

Comment: Sorry, I've provided a fiddle that should illustrate things better (and fixed some JS oversights).

Comment: behic now it works perfectly! huge or even more bigger thanks :)